# Not able to use swipe left or swipe right iframe Phonegap iOS

Tags: html, cordova, dom, cross-platform

I have implemented slider in the ios phonegap app on swipe right it opens the slider and on swipe left it closes the slider

but in one page i have used iframe and the swipe left and swipe right is not working on the iframe please help me?????

Comment: You should target the iframe container, not the iframe element, can you post your HTML? Did you use jquery mobile or other swipe library?